# how to hide or merge same data fields in grafana chart

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-api

I have a grafana chart which has multiple same values which i want to merge to single data
.[check this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckYA1.png)
Example : the chart in link has  "activity - ExternalNonFinancialBaseRepository (findByStateIn) "  occurences multiple times .
I want that to be only a single occurence.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promql aggregations. I think `sum by` here is what you want

By that, you can sum values of same fields:

```
sum by (class) (YOUR_QUERY)
```

Take a look at docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/